# CSS *:not(img) not working

Tags: html, css, image

I searched various sources and all are saying the same thing.

This code:

```
*:not(img) {
display: none;
}
```

Should hide everything except images. But it hides images too.

Whats wrong?

Comment: It probably hides it's parent element and thereby itself. if it is a direct element of `body` then try -- `body *:not(img)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer you are probably right. Its not direct, its nested somewhere deep. I will use * {color: white; background: white} instead to hide everything except image. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As spotted in comment, this will make the container of images disappear thus the images too. So here another idea to achieve what you want:

You create an overlay that will cover the whole page with a big `z-index` and then you make your image `positon:relative` with a **bigger** `z-index`:

```css
/* The normal CSS of the page */

body {
  margin: 0
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.box-2 {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}


/* The CSS to keep only the images*/

body:after {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  background:#fff;
}

img {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9999999;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/400/"> some text
</div>

<div class="box-2">
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/400/"> some text
</div>
<p>lorem ipsum lorem ipusme lorem ipsum lorem ipusme lorem ipsum lorem ipusme</p>

<ul>
  <li>item1</li>
  <li>item2</li>
  <li>item3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

Every image is *inside* of some other element, e.g. a `div` or even just the `body`. When you set those elements to be `display: none`, their contents are hidden as well, and that's everything.